# Node server segmentation fault (core dumped), When it receives websocket connection request

Tags: node.js, apache, socket.io

I am using Node sever with Socketio to make a simple chat application. my website is SSL. I am using apache server with proxy to Node server for websocket connections. When my node server receives first request using polling, it make a successful connection. On client side connection event is called and I can also see socket.id but right after it when socketio internal functionality tries to upgrade the connection to websocket.. Node server crashes with an error on the terminal 
Segmentation fault (Core dumped)
Just this... I am new to node.js and socket io. help me how can I solve this issue.. and also tell me if there is a way to debug the server using shell commands, as I don't have desktop access to my server. I only connect to it with SSH access..

Here is my server code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('apache-selfsigned.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('apache-selfsigned.crt')
};
var serverPort = 9001;

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('new secure connection');
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
server.listen(serverPort, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at %s port', serverPort);
});
```

here is my client code

```
socket = io('https://www.MyApacheServer.net/');
socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log("Connected");
    console.log(socket.id);
});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log("DisConnected");
});
socket.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('System', e ? e : 'A unknown error occurred');
});
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    alert(msg);
});
```

Comment: This sounds like some binary code that plugs into node.js (perhaps in socket.io) is not installed or compiled properly.  I would suggest uninstalling socket.io and then reinstalling.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 for the tip... I did 
npm cache clear ----- rm -rf node_modules ----- node install...
but it does not help... same error again...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the P programming language, please do not use the [tag:p] tag.

Answer (score 2):

please try this:

```
io = require('socket.io')(server, { wsEngine: 'ws' });
```

The problem is about the uws.
This worked for me

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Also allowed me to find a related issue on  the socket.io github page https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2945

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by using

```
socket = io('https://www.MyApacheServer.net/', {transports:['polling'], upgrade: true});
```

I am not sure why this was happening... even in my case it was not working with this statement

```
socket = io('https://www.MyApacheServer.net/', {transports:['websocket']});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt --auto-remove purge npm
sudo apt --auto-remove purge nodejs
```

Please run this command. It works for me.